# C: simultaneous reading from and writing to file

Tags: c, file-io

**What i would like to do:**
Read bits from one file (input file), and write these (with some probability) inverted bits to other file (output file).

**What is the problem:**
Probability idea seem not to be working properly. And more importantly, output file always contains more characters then the original input file, while they should contain equal number of characters.

*In this code sample, instead of inverted bits i have put 'x' and 'y', so that it is more obvious that output file contains more characters*

*INPUT file*: 01001

*OUTPUT file*: xyxxxyx

**The code:**

```
void invert_bits(FILE **input, FILE **output, double prob){
srand(clock());
char symbol;
while((symbol = getc(*input)) != EOF){
    double result = rand()/RAND_MAX;
    if(result < prob){
        if(simbol == '0'){
            char bit = 'x';
            fprintf(*output, &bit);
        }
        else{
            char bit = 'y';
            fprintf(*output, &bit);
        }
    }else{
        fprintf(*output, &symbol);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure it's writing to the right file? You can check by looking at the file's timestamp, or renaming the file but not changing the program.

Comment: Passing the address of a `char` as the format parameter to a `printf` is almost certainly wrong. What probably happens is that the local variable with `y` is in memory before the local variable with `x`, and they're both followed by a `\0`, so anytime you try to print `y` you print `yx` instead.

Comment: You can't "write bits" - only bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the `fprintf` function properly.

The function's signature is:

> int fprintf ( FILE * stream, const char * **format**, ... );

Instead of a null terminated string, you're providing it with an address of a `char`, which might follow by a null character, or might not.

The correct way of printing a character with the *printf functions is:

```
fprintf(*output, "%c", bit);
```

P.S. Why are you receiving a pointer to the file handle, i.e. `FILE**` and not just `FILE*`?

Answer (score 2):

`(f)printf` expects a *format* string as its second argument. You are providing it with the address of a `char`, which is not even a valid string (since it is not NUL-terminated).

Don't do that. It's a bad habit. When you use `printf`, `fprintf` or `sprintf` *always use a format string*. (Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string) for more information.)

You could have used `fprintf(*output, "%c", bit);` but it would be a lot simpler to just print the character with `fputc(bit, *output);`

I don't understand why you feel the need to pass the `FILE*` arguments as pointers, by the way.